# Overriding ToString but when printing an array it shows the type

Tags: c#

While I am printing values, I am not getting value instead it prints type.
In `PlayerBO` class `Console.WriteLine(playerList);` prints `player[]`
but I need to print value.

What is wrong with my code?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player[] p= new Player[100];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of players");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new Player();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the player name");
            p[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the country name");
            p[i].Country = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the skill");
            p[i].Skill = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        PlayerBO pb=new PlayerBO();
        pb.DisplayPlayerDetails(p);
    }
}

public class Player
{
    private string _country;
    private string _skill;
    private string _name;
    public Player(string _name, string _country, string _skill)
    {
        this._name = _name;
        this._country = _country;
        this._skill = _skill;
    }
    public Player() { }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set { this._name = value; }
    }

    public string Country
    {
        get { return this._country; }
        set { this._country = value; }
    }

    public string Skill
    {
        get { return this._skill; }
        set { this._skill = value; }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,0}", Name, Country, Skill);
    }
}

public class PlayerBO
{
    public void DisplayPlayerDetails(Player[] playerList)
    {
        playerList = new Player[100];
        Console.WriteLine("Player Details");
        Console.WriteLine(playerList);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do like this. You have to iterate through array to print value.

Comment: While you have overriden `ToString` on your `Player` item this doesn't effect the implementation of `ToString` on an array which is why you need to do as the current answer suggests and iterate through the array.

Comment: Side note: In the future please only post the relavent parts of the code to reproduce the problem and not a full code dump, see the following on how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(playerList)` will execute the `ToString` implemented for the array - Which is not the same as overriding the `ToString` of an object type in that array.

To print the values in the array you need to iterate over it:

```
foreach(var item in playerList) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Or another way is using `string.Join`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, playerList));
```

Also, have a look at Auto-Properties:

```
//Instead of this:
public string Name
{
    get { return this._name; }
    set { this._name = value; }
}

//You can do this:
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Side note: although `\n` is fine I'd recommend using `Environment.NewLine` just for good practice.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Yap :) agree with you. Corrected

Comment: @Gayathri - great :) happy it helped you